# How to generate double value from TimeSpan

Tags: .net, double, timespan

I have to calculate the relative time which is

```
TimeSpan relativeTime = currentTime.Subtract(startTime);
```

Next I would like to convert relativeTime to double value which should be consisted of seconds and milliseconds (seconds.milliseconds).

Does anyone know what is the best way to generate such double value from time difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`double seconds = (currentTime - startTime).TotalSeconds;`

Answer (score 3):

Eh, `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`. Or if you explicitly want to attempt a granularity of milliseconds (not totally possible with `double`), then:

```
((long) relativeTime.TotalMilliseconds) / 1000.0
```

Comment: Yep. Fixed. Now to fill minimal comment char count.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
relativeTime.TotalSeconds
```

This returns whole and fractional, as a double.

Answer (score 1):

```
timeSpan.TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something:

```
t.TotalSeconds;
```